# How to get the same ciphertext when encrypting the same plaintext multiple times

Tags: android, encryption

I'm not aware of encryption/decryption very much. Using below code for encryption

```
    class EncryptExample {

    private static int KEY_LENGTH = 256;
    private static final String CIPHER_ALGORITHM = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";
    private static String DELIMITER = "]";

    public static String encrypt(String plaintext, SecretKey key, byte[] salt) {
        try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER_ALGORITHM);

            byte[] iv = generateIv(cipher.getBlockSize());
            IvParameterSpec ivParams = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, ivParams);
            byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(plaintext.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            if (salt != null) {
                return String.format("%s%s%s%s%s", toBase64(salt), DELIMITER, toBase64(iv), DELIMITER, toBase64(cipherText));
            }
            return String.format("%s%s%s", toBase64(iv), DELIMITER, toBase64(cipherText));
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static byte[] generateIv(int length) {
        byte[] b = new byte[length];
        new SecureRandom().nextBytes(b);
        return b;
    }

    public static String toBase64(byte[] bytes) {
        return Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);
    }

    public static byte[] fromBase64(String base64) {
        return Base64.decode(base64, Base64.NO_WRAP);
    }
}
```

It's working fine for encryption, but when I'm getting encrypted value, it's always different for same text. Can you please let me know that how can it be done if I can get same encrypted value for a same plaint text?

Comment: *"Can you please let me know that how can it be done if I can get same encrypted value for a same plaint text?"* That's a security property. You should keep it. Why don't you want that property? Even if the IV and therefore ciphertext are different each time, it doesn't reduce your ability to decrypt the ciphertext.

Comment: I completely agree @ArtjomB. but problem is that we're using encrypted value again as a key for saving status of a feature (feature on/off).
That Key we save in preference. This key is actually username so that we can track status of feature as per user.

Comment: You can certainly simply use a static IV, but I'm sure there are more appropriate solutions in your case. Have you thought about an additional token in your database or a hash of the plaintext before encryption?

Comment: I got it about your 1st suggestion. Let me try. But I'm sorry, I didn't get about your 2nd approach? Are you saying instead of using encrypted value as a key, I've to use a separably hashed value for key?

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're trying to do. Perhaps you can ask a question on [security.se] to describe your situation and what the best approach would be. I hardly think using the ciphertext as a lookup key is the way to go.